# Replacing spaces with NULL values by comparing two CSV files using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Say that I have two csv files:

`csvfile1`:

```
name      Dept  City      
sree,     CSE,  Bengaluru,  
vatsasa,  ECE,  Hyd,      
          IT,   VJA,      
capini,   Mech, TPTY,   
DTP,      Civil,kandra
Bengaluru,ECM,  TVM,      
sre,      ECS,  MNGL,   
vatsas,         Kochi,    
          Nano, TVM,      
capmin,         Tech,       
DTP9,     CSS,  Kochi,    
          ESS,  TVM,    
sree0,    RSS,  MNGL,
```

`csvfile2`:

```
name, Dept, City, Address
```

I would like to check all the columns of `csvfile2` present in `csvfile1`.

1. If present, check whether any one of the columns in `csvfile1` contains spaces. If spaces are present, replace spaces with value `NULL` and write all the columns to a new csv file, `csvfile3`, column-wise.
2. If not present, write those missing columns along with existing ones to `csvfile3`. In addition, values of those missing columns should be shown as `NULL` in `csvfile3`, and spaces under existing columns should be replaced with `NULL`

The below is expected output:

```
name      Dept  City      Address
sree,     CSE,  Bengaluru,NULL
vatsasa,  ECE,  Hyd,      NULL
NULL,     IT,   VJA,      NULL
capini,   NULL, Mech,     NULL
DTP,      Civil,NULL,     NULL
Bengaluru,ECM,  TVM,      NULL
sre,      ECS,  MNGL,     NULL
vatsas,   NULL, Kochi,    NULL
NULL,     Nano, TVM,      NULL
capmin,   NULL, Tech,     NULL
DTP9,     CSS,  Kochi,    NULL
NULL,     ESS,  TVM,      NULL
sree0,    RSS,  MNGL,     NULL
```

I have written the following code:

```
f=open('csvfile2.csv', 'r')
g=csv.reader(f)
first=next(g, None)
print('lenght of first list', len(first))
f1=open('csvfile1.csv','r')
h=csv.reader(f1)
second=next(h,None)
print('lenght of first list', len(second))
f2=open('csvfile3', 'w')
writer=csv.writer(f2)
count=0
if len(second) < len(first):
    for i in first:
        if not i in second:
            for count in range:
                writer.writerows('Null')
                print('null')
        else:
            ind=second.index(i)
                for j in second:
                    if not j[ind]:
                        writer.writerows(j[ind].replace(' ','Null'))                            
                    else:
                        writer.writerows(j[ind])
```

Output of above code:

```
name, Dept, City, Address
N
U
L
L
N
U
L
L
N
U
L
L
N
U
L
L
N
U
L
L
```

I have written code on AWS EC2 instance and planning to use the same for AWS Lambda too.

Comment: Where there are gaps, I assume the format is actually `vatsas,,Kochi` rather than `vatsas,         Kochi,` - is this the case?

Comment: @Phydeaux: That's true.

Answer (score 0):

To directly operate on csv files could be very difficult. I would suggest use of pandas that work with tabular data structure because it is very efficient and minimizes code.

**Sample code:**

```
import pandas as pd 

# READ BOTH FILES AS TABULAR DATA STRUCTURE
# PROVIDE FILE PATH
csv_file_one = pd.read_csv("csv_file_one.csv")
csv_file_two = pd.read_csv("csv_file_two.csv")

# REPLACE EMPTY VALUES WITH NULL IN CSV ONE
csv_file_one.fillna(value='NULL', inplace=True)

header_of_csv_two = list(csv_file_two.columns.values)

# IF CSV FILE ONE DOESN'T HAS COLUMN
# OF CSV TWO, THEN IT WILL CREATE THAT
# WITH NULL VALUES
for each_col in header_of_csv_two:
    if each_col not in csv_file_one.columns:
        csv_file_one[each_col] = 'NULL'

# WRITING TO CSV
# PROVIDE FILE PATH
csv_file_one.to_csv("csv_file_three.csv", index=False)
```

**Sample output:**

```
name      dept       city  address
ram        NULL  kathmandu    NULL
kiran  computer       NULL    NULL
kumar     civil      patan    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, but I have to use the same code for aws lambda function. But before replicating the code, I have to install pandas which is additional part to do. Hence, I am trying out with csv commands. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use `pandas`, here is a solution using `csv`:

```
import csv

with open("csvfile1.csv") as csv_1,\
     open("csvfile2.csv") as csv_2,\
     open("csvfile3.csv", "w") as csv_3:

    reader_1 = csv.reader(csv_1)
    reader_2 = csv.reader(csv_2)
    writer = csv.writer(csv_3)

    headers_1 = next(reader_1)
    headers_2 = next(reader_2)

    insert_null_at = []
    for i, header in enumerate(headers_2):
        if header not in headers_1:
            insert_null_at.append(i)

    writer.writerow(headers_2)
    for row in reader_1:
        for i in insert_null_at:
            row.insert(i, "")

        writer.writerow([item if item != "" else "NULL" for item in row])
```

As discussed above, this assumes the format of `csvfile1` is actually:

```
name,Dept,City
sree,CSE,Bengaluru
vatsasa,ECE,Hyd
,IT,VJA
capini,Mech,TPTY
DTP,Civil,kandra
Bengaluru,ECM,TVM
sre,ECS,MNGL
vatsas,,Kochi
,Nano,TVM
capmin,,Tech
DTP9,CSS,Kochi
,ESS,TVM
sree0,RSS,MNGL
```

Comment: I have tried above code and here is the output:              name,Dept,City,Address
sree, CSE,NULL,NULL,Bengaluru,
vatsasa,ECE,NULL,NULL,Hyd,
NULL,IT,NULL,NULL,VJA,
capini,Mech,NULL,NULL,TPTY,
DTP,Civil,NULL,NULL,kandra,NULL
Bengaluru,ECM,NULL,NULL,TVM,
sre,ECS,NULL,NULL,MNGL,
vatsas,NULL,NULL,NULL,Kochi,
NULL,Nano,NULL,NULL,TVM,
capmin,NULL,NULL,NULL,Tech,
DTP9,CSS,NULL,NULL,Kochi,
NULL,ESS,NULL,NULL,TVM,
sree0,RSS,NULL,NULL,MNGL,NULL                                                         But this is not exptected output :)

Comment: @srivatsasa That's strange, it works for me. Can you edit the the question to show the exact format of `csvfile1` (i.e. how it is when you open it with a text editor)? Is it like in my answer?

Comment: My Apologises, taken correct format and its working now :) @Phydeaux

Comment: I have tried the code with some modifications on AWS Lambda. If you can be able to help, Could you please check below link for issue :)  
                                            
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036134/python-bytes-io-usage-on-aws-lambda-and-second-iteration-of-csv-file) @Phydeaux

Comment: Looking for help on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136927/replace-spaces-with-null-in-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment97014229_55136927 @Phydeaux